# csv file output new line

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have make code that can open Facebook profile from .`txt` file and get phone number and save it to `csv` file everything work fine but the output every number in new line this is my code

```
def writecsv(namefile,type,header=None):
    with open(namefile, 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        if header is not None:
            w.riterow(header)
        for row in type:
            w.writerow(row)
        try:
            a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#pagelet_contact > div > div._4qm1 > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > div._4bl7._3xdi._52ju > span')
            print (a.text)
            if a.text != 'Mobile phones':
                not_found_account.append(account)
                print ("{0} not found".format(account))
            else:
                phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/span/ul/li/span').text
                                print (phone.text)
                active_account.append(account)
                print ("{0} active account".format(account))
        except:
            print (phone)
            continue
    print (phone)
    writecsv('facebook/FB_available_account.csv', phone)
```

the python print looks like this very good

```
100003187973663?sk=about&section=contact-info
Mobile phones
+20 1125067822
```

but the output in csv file looks like this

```
+

2

0



1

1

2

etc..
```

where is the wrong please ?
thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: let me know if the below answer helped you

Comment: yes, i have solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To write in each cell, example would be*

```
import csv

my_data = "Example"

with open("FB_available_account.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([my_data])
```